# Unable to connect to Azure DataLake Storage gen 1, forbidden error

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

I am using .net4.8. 
I need  to connect to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1.

I found below sample on github:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-lake-store-adls-dot-net-get-started/

Now in Azure account :

[image]

Registered New Application, got Application Id, tenantId, Client secret 
[image]

```
// Obtain AAD token
        var creds = new ClientCredential(applicationId, clientSecret);
        var clientCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, creds).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Create ADLS client object
        AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient(adlsAccountFQDN, clientCreds);

        try
        {
            string fileName = "/test/xyz.txt";


            //Read file contents
            using (var readStream = new StreamReader(client.GetReadStream(fileName)))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = readStream.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }





        }
```

Line using (var readStream = new StreamReader(client.GetReadStream(fileName)))
            { throws an exception:

[image]

[image]

xyz.txt is both available at root as well as within /test/xyz.txt.

How to fix this exception?

Comment: Have you set the firewall? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data#set-ip-address-range-for-data-access

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly an permission issue. Have you added you application to access your data lake as per the below screenshot, this is mandatory to have service to service authentication.

[image]

[image]

Please make sure to check the below thread to ensure you have the right privilege:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory

It worked for me. Try this and see if it helps else will take a look and debug with you.